# How does Highland.js implement backpressure?

Tags: javascript, stream, highland.js, backpressure

How exactly does `Highland.js` implement backpressure? I'm curious about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/caolan/highland/blob/2.6.0/lib/index.js#L808

It looks like consumers ask the stream they are consuming to check any  other consumers it may have every so often. If any of those consumers are in the `paused` state, the parent stream pauses as well.